# Mean squared [X] or Mean [X] squared?

Tags: probability, terminology, average

If I have two functions, as below, which one is "Mean [X] squared" and which is "Mean squared [X]"?

Would I be correct in saying the former is number 1 and the latter is number 2?

Thanks in advance

```
1: <X^2>

2: <X>^2
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, *"Mean squared [X]"* refers to the first one, as in [mean squared error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_squared_error).

For the second one, I would use something that clearly disambiguates from 1st, e.g., "squared mean of [X]" or "the square of the mean of [X]".